# How to install 'libgnome2-0' in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies

I wanted to install the dependencies for *Storage Made Easy* Linux application (basically to sync with OneDrive)

Installed all the dependencies except one `libgnome2-0`, The error coming during installation is

```
$ sudo dpkg -i storagemadeeasy_4.9.4.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package storagemadeeasy.
(Reading database ... 475763 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack storagemadeeasy_4.9.4.deb ...
Unpacking storagemadeeasy (4.9-4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of storagemadeeasy:
 storagemadeeasy depends on libgnome2-0; however:
  Package libgnome2-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package storagemadeeasy (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 storagemadeeasy
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install libgnome2-0`

The error coming as

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgnome2-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgnome2-0' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this package dependency problem.

My ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 19.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`libgnome2-0`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgnome) isn’t available in Ubuntu 19.10; it was removed as part of the general GNOME 2 removal (sometime between 18.04 and 19.10).

You *could* install the package from Ubuntu 18.04, but I think a better approach would be to use another OneDrive-compatible client, such as [`rclone`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rclone).

Comment: Oh my God. There is no workaround ??? I have paid to them.

Comment: As i am in middle of experiment, I cannot possibly upgrade or downgrade Ubuntu

Comment: I’m not recommending an upgrade or downgrade; you can download the package and install it manually. And if you’re paying for support, you should use that instead of asking here ;-).

Comment: OK. Asked in support. They replied back and told that they have a different Linux built for Ubuntu 19.10 which is compatible to be installed without the requirement of `libgnome2-0` . They will mail the link of installation on request.